# How to use multiple paperscopes on a single canvas in paperjs?

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I'm trying to create multiple canvases each with it's own scope. However I've hit a few problems that I didn't encounter when working with a single canvas and scope.

I have an array of scopes and try switching between them using `scopeArray[n].activate();` This however seems to not initiate the `paperScope.project` and I can't assign layers or draw.

Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

I set up the canvases based on the size of an array and store them in an object:

```
paper.install(window);
...  
var paperPad = {};
var layers = {
    'BACK': 0,
    'DRAW': 1,
    'CONTROL': 2,
    'FRONT': 3
}

 function setupCanvas(){

// init canvas and calculate width/height/centre
for(var c in canvasList){

  var el = document.createElement("canvas");
  var id = '' + canvasList[c][0] + '' + canvasList[c][1] + '' + canvasList[c][2];

  el.width = canvasWidth;
  el.height = canvasHeight;
  el.setAttribute('id', id);
  el.setAttribute('class', 'padcanvas');
  document.body.appendChild(el);

  paperPad[id] = new paper.PaperScope();
  paperPad[id].setup(el);

}
```

and then I attempt to automatically setup layers by accessing the project global but I get an error saying that project us null.

function setupLayers() {

```
for(var p in paperPad){

  paperPad[p].activate();
  project.layers[0].setName('BACK');

  for(var l in layers) {
    if(!project.layers[layers[l]]){
      var layer = new Layer();
      layer.setName(l);
    }
  }
}
```

}

same happens in the draw functions

function draw() {

```
for(var p in paperPad) {

  paperPad[p].activate();

  // draw functions
}
```

}

I'm sure there's something I'm missing about how the scoping works.

Answer (score 1):

paperjs does not update the global variable `project` even though you've installed paper globals via `paper.install(window)` in pure JavaScript mode. If you set `project = paperPad[id];` it should work. I always end up using `paper.project` and manually updating it because I started that way and it seems natural at this point.

But paper doesn't manage keeping `project` up-to-date in JavaScript mode.

Comment: I believe the documentation used to note this point specifically but doesn't seem to any longer - in fact, it says that they will be kept up-to-date if `paper.install(window)` is executed. It's possible that the documentation has been updated for a pending release of the library; I know a few changes that haven't been released have made it into the documentation.